# How to retain history (e.g. last reading positions) after batch converting .epubs using kepubify

Tags: epub, conversion, kobo

I have copied my entire library of my Kobo Libra reader to my hard drive and used `kepubify` to convert all the regular epubs to the kepub format (specifically the command `kepubify-windows-64bit.exe --update "E:\New folder - Copy"`), If I replace all of the existing epubs on the eReader with the converted versions, it would delete all the existing history and last pages. Is there a way to replace the files while retaining the data?